# I'm having problem with my C function code

Tags: c

I want it show me sum of numbers that I enter for example:123=1+2+3 but it wants number from me forever

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int totalOfNumbers(int number)
{
    int i, total = 0;
    while (number >= 0)
    {
        i = number % 10;
        total += i;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    return total;
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("%d", totalOfNumbers(x));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm entering number then it wants more numbers from me.

Comment: 0/10 is 0. you're repeating while number greater than **or equal to** 0

Comment: So you have an infinite loop. @pmg has the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

As [pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58528547/im-having-problem-with-my-function-codeim-new#comment103381266_58528547) pointed out you are falling into an infinite loop. This line:

```
while (number >= 0)
```

Should instead be:

```
while (number > 0)
```